# IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient is missing PartitionResolver in Document DB

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

When returned DocumentClient `AsReliable`, it doesn't have PartitionResolvers. Any way to get around this?

```
var documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPointUrl), authorizationKey);

var documentRetryStrategy = new DocumentDbRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DefaultExponential) { FastFirstRetry = true };
return documentClient.AsReliable(documentRetryStrategy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the underlying DocumentClient object to register the PartitionResolvers.

Comment: Yes, I can see UnderlyingClient property is available. Can this be used interchangeably and is there a best practice on when to use IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient and when to use DocumentClient?

Answer (score 3):

The `IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient` implementation that you get from `.AsReliable(..)` is just a wrapper around the original `DocumentClient`, which executes every method of the original (underlying) client in a retry block by using provided retry strategy. No magic. Built-in `DocumentDbRetryStrategy` is design to eliminate majority of the transient network/service/throttling issues.

Answering your initial question - you can either set `PartitionResolvers` on the original client before wrapping it with `.AsReliable(..)` or you can access the collection later through `UnderlyingClient` property. `UnderlyingClient` property holds the same instance that was passed to the `.AsReliable(..)` extension method.

Regarding best practices around using `DocumentClient` vs `IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient`: if you need to have more reliable communication between the client and the server, that will automatically retry on transient failures described above - then you should consider using `.AsReliable(..)`. If your scenario does not require all documents to be persisted in the storage (in case of a logging/trace, for example) and you will "swallow" all exceptions anyway - then there is nothing wrong with using `DocumentClient` directly to reduce the time spent in additional retries.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. Is there any official documentation to read more on this?